# iTunes interrupts shutdown

Tags: itunes, shutdown

I'm on Lion.

Everytime I try to shut down my laptop, I get a popup that tells me that iTunes has interrupted the shut down.

When I try to shut down again (without quitting iTunes, or changing anything), the shutdown proceeds normally.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: I would have to ask how you are going about the shut down process and how many apps you are running when shutting down. It may be possible that iTunes is running a fairly high load, downloading or syncing with the cloud/genius/purchase lists. Do you get any error messages or issues when quitting iTunes independently? It may also be possible that the database for iTunes is damaged in some way (maybe too frequent of force quits, etc.). Does the issue occur on every user on the computer with their own iTunes Libraries? Hope this gives you some ideas of how to test. Cheers